# Continuity and discontinuity of a function

Tags: continuity

[How do we know from looking at the function, if it is continuous or discontinuous and at what points?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzwxK.png)

How can a function be continuous if there are "gaps"? 
If you can, can you give the answer in as simple terms as possible?

Thank You

Comment: You can have continuity at a point without it being continuous everywhere.

Comment: I agree but from this function, is it only continuous between each integer? If so, what would that set look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function with "gaps," as you say, is not continuous. That said, a function can be continuous at some points, but not be continuous on the whole. The function in your link is continuous at some points, and discontinuous at others. The problem asks about points where it is discontinuous. Can you determine which points will be the locations of gaps, and at which the function will be continuous?

Comment: That's where my problem lies. If x is an integer, then f(x) will be x. If x is not an integer, f(x) will be 0. This means the if one was to draw the function, it would not be continuous since we will always be jumping between 0 and the integers.

Comment: That's right, but if we just look between the integers, it is continuous at those points. It is discontinuous at each integer (except zero).

Comment: This may sound silly, but how does it prove it is continuous for when x is not an integer, since there are gaps in between each integer?

Comment: Because there are no gaps around points that are not integers.

Comment: I am still unclear as to why it is discontinuous at the integers

Comment: At each nonzero integer point $x$, $f(x)=x\neq 0$. But there are points $y$ close to $x$ so that $f(y)=0$.

Comment: Normally in an introductory calculus class, you define a point $x_{0}$ to be continuous if $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{-}}f(x) = f(x_{0})$. Calculate those three quantities at an integer other than $x_{0}=0$ and see what you get.

Comment: Oh ok that make sense